# How to transpose in power bi desktop

Tags: powerbi, transpose

I am having a table with 3 columns, where I need to transpose using Power Bi desktop. This is the structure I need:

[image: See this picture]

I started using Power Query Editor, but seems like it to not transforming the way I need in the picture above. Any ideas?

Comment: Use Unpivot in Power Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the *row* column and select unpivot other columns from the transform tab on the ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

Inside Power Query, click on **Transform**, then **Unpivot Columns**.

Three options are available, pick the one that fits best for you.

You may check how-to using the following screenshot:
[Unpivot Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjOd0.png)